# Issue with Exception handling in Xamarin - Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using the following helper method to Open external app's in my android application.

```
using Android.Content;

 namespace xyzab
 {
   public static class ExternalAppLauncher
   {
    #region Constants

    const string FacebooUrlSchema = "fb://page/34530418978";
    const string FacebookAppName = "com.facebook.katana";

    const string TwitterUrlSchema = "twitter://user?id=1534530";
    const string TwitterAppName = "com.twitter.android";



    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Method that Launches the pre-installed app 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The app.</returns>
    /// <param name="launcher">Launcher.</param>
    public static Intent LaunchApp (Launcher launcher)
    {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (launcher) {

        case Launcher.Facebook:

            try {
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (FacebooUrlSchema);
                intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException) {
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("market://details?id=" + FacebookAppName);
                intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri);
            }
            break;



        case  Launcher.Twitter:
            try {
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (TwitterUrlSchema);
                intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException) {
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("market://details?id=" + TwitterAppName);
                intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri);
            }
            break;
        }
        return intent;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

The intention behind the helper is, If the target app is already installed i have to open the app. Otherwise I have to open the market place.

But here my issue is if the app is not present in the phone. It is throwing
a **ActivityNotFoundException** But that is not enters into my try catch block.

Even in the calling place I added try catch. That is also not catching the exception. What is wrong here.

```
    void ABCD(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var intent = ExternalAppLauncher.LaunchApp(Launcher.Twitter);
            if (null != intent)
                StartActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is the best way to check whether an app is installed on the device. Android has built-in ways to do that.

I would have a look at the `PackageManager` class. It has a method `GetPackageInfo` which provides you more information about a particular package.

The PackageManager can be used from any Context class (e.g. an Activity or a Service)

For example, you could create a method like below:

```
private bool IsAppInstalled(string packageName)
{
    try
    {
       PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(packageName, PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
       return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You could then call this method like this:

```
IsAppInstalled("com.twitter.android");
```